# Retrieve group of data in the row to columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
EmpId   X   Y

U27     1   1
U28     1   2
U29     1   3
U30     2   1
U31     2   2
U32     2   3
U33     3   1
U34     3   2
U35     3   3
```

I have a Table of data shown above.I want to retrieve the  data like shown below

```
U27 U28 U29
U30 U31 U32
U33 U34 U35
```

Please give your suggestions and ideas do resolve this problem
Thanks
Binu Venu

Answer (score 2):

```
select [1], [2], [3]
from YourTable
pivot (min(EmpId) for Y in ([1], [2], [3])) as p
```

Try here on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63245/pivot)